# object backing the pointer will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression

Tags: c++, list, pointers, vector, iterator

I've created three classes to create a graph. The Edge, the Vertex and the Graph itself.
I'm using two iterators in the graph class, one to go through the vector of vertices, and another one, by dereferencing the first one to go through each item in the list of edges inside a Vertex and I'm getting hit with the error below.

```
dirgraphimpl.cpp:100:38: warning: object backing the pointer will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression [-Wdangling-gsl]
                for (auto iterator = vertices.at(id1).getList().begin(); iterator != vertices.at(id1).getList().end(); ++iterator) {
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
dirgraphimpl.cpp:137:39: warning: object backing the pointer will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression [-Wdangling-gsl]
                for (auto jiterator = (*iterator).getList().begin(); jiterator != (*iterator).getList().end(); ++jiterator) {
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
dirgraphimpl.cpp:152:39: warning: object backing the pointer will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression [-Wdangling-gsl]
                for (auto jiterator = (*iterator).getList().begin(); jiterator != (*iterator).getList().end(); ++jiterator) {
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
dirgraphimpl.cpp:225:39: warning: object backing the pointer will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression [-Wdangling-gsl]
                for (auto jiterator = (*iterator).getList().begin(); jiterator != (*iterator).getList().end(); ++jiterator) {
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 warnings generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Lines 98 - 107, 130 - 160, 222 - 231.
https://github.com/PeterAvgerinos/GraphImpl/blob/main/dirgraphimpl.cpp

Comment: `getList` returns by value, so that temporary object will die at the end of the full expression, leaving you with a dangling iterator.

Comment: `getList()` returns by value, meaning it returns a temporary object.

Comment: **AFTER** you get this working. Go for a code review at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (Note they will only review working code)

Answer (score 0):

There's so many problems with your code I don't even know where to start. In no particular order, they're all *very* bad:

Your `Vertex.getList()` returning a `list<Edge>` *copies the entire list on every call*. And you call it a lot. Return a `const list<Edge> &` instead, or equivalent (`shared_ptr` etc).

The `for (auto iterator = vertices.at(id1).getList().begin(); iterator != vertices.at(id1).getList().end(); ++iterator)` iterator code you keep copy & pasting everywhere *iterates on lists that don't exist anymore* because of the above problem. It also checks for the end iterator of another list. You're just lucky your STL implementation uses a null pointer for the end of lists, which is valid between them, but that is literally luck.

Use a simple `for(const auto &edge: vertices[id1].getList())` instead, which stores the list once, and calls `begin()`, `iterator::++` and `end()` on it as necessary.

In fact the copying problem isn't even limited to the edge, you keep copying everything. You need to learn about (const) references!

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to programming that's why it's so bad. I'm still getting an error in line 184. 'this' argument has type 'const list<Edge>', but method is not marked const

Comment: So, mark your function as `const`, if I'm reading your message right (and that is, replacing "error" with "warning"). Ie, `const list<Edge> &getList() const { return ...; }`

Comment: But really what you should be doing is make your vertices enumerable (ie implement `begin()` and `end()`, so you can then simply do `for(const auto &edge: vertex)`. `getList()` is a really bad name because it says literally nothing about what it does, and doesn't even need to exist.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've fixed your code for you at https://github.com/PeterAvgerinos/GraphImpl/pull/1